# how to shuffle char "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" without repeating

Tags: c++, random, shuffle

```
const char chars[] = "abcdef ...."; 
char result[...];
memcpy(result, chars, sizeof(chars)); 
for (unsigned i = 0; i < (sizeof(chars)-1); ++i) {
    unsigned j = rand() % sizeof(chars);
    char tmp = result[j];
    result[j] = result[i];
    result[i] = tmp;
}
```

problem writing the result to a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the character value 0 isn't mapped to A. Rather, a character which will will be printed as A is equal to 65. You can see the full table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/), if you ever need it.

Anyway, the code solution is simple. 
Instead of

```
cout<<letter[i]<<" ";
```

You can do:

```
cout<<letter[i]+'A'-1<<" ";
```

(the -1 is because you numbered the letters from 1 to 26 instead o 0 to 25).

Comment: Yeah, it'd be neater without the +1's,  which are totally unnecessary here.

Comment: i tried your method , it doesnt give me funny character but it give me number 65- 90 how to i display them as alphabet?

Comment: @user1526669: Without the -1 it will work. Currently, it's casting everything to integers (chars promote to integers). So either remove the +-1, or do cout<< (char) (letter[i] +'A' -1) <<...

Answer (score 7):

The answer to "how to shuffle" something in C++ is to use one of the standard library's shuffling algorithms. An easy way to do it would be to put it in an [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), and use [std::random_shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle):

```
std::string s = "abcdef ...." ;
std::random_shuffle(s.begin(), s.end());
```

You can also do it with an array:

```
char letters[] = {'a', 'b', ..... };
std::random_shuffle(letters, letters+26);
```

Comment: by using this method, is the shuffling fixed?
i want the program to generate a different shuffling without having repeating.

Comment: @user1526669 it would be fixed but you can have a handle on the seeds used for random number generation, so can use something like the date or whatever to produce a different key each time you run the program. The docs [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) should give more clues.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go: [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

And a [`C++` implementation](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet4302.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
const char chars[] = "abcdef ...."; 
char result[...];
memcpy(result, chars, sizeof(chars)); 
for (unsigned i = 0; i < (sizeof(chars)-1); ++i) {
    unsigned j = rand() % sizeof(chars);
    char tmp = result[j];
    result[j] = result[i];
    result[i] = tmp;
}
```

If you use STL then std::random_shuffle is preferred.